# Merging partially overlapping sheets in Excel while keeping columns separate?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have sheets with partially overlapping records for each month:

```
Person      Jan
Alice       $20
Bob         $10
Charlie     $30
```

and

```
 Person     Feb
 Alice      $15
 Charlie    $10
 Dave       $40
```

I want to combine them into a single sheet like so:

```
 Person     Jan    Feb
 Alice      $20    $15
 Bob        $10    $0
 Charlie    $30    $10
 Dave       $0     $40
```

Is there a convenient way to do this in Excel? I've looked into the consolidate feature, but that seems to combine the columns, which I don't want.

Comment: if you have PowerQuery it was designed for exactly stuff like this

Comment: why don't you use `=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A2;MATCH(E1;B1:B2;0));0)`, where `A1:A2` is the range on data you want to bring to your consolidates sheet; `E2` is your key and `B1:B2` is the range of data where you will be look `E2` key. Is like `VLOOKUP` but a little bit more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table with multiple ranges:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-pivottable-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5

If you right-click the pivot table and select PivotTable Options, you can customise it to hide bits you don't want and set 0 value for empty cells.

[image]

Hide headings and total rows you don't want to see:

[image]

[image]

Manually hide the first row (ie Sum of Value).

Then select the figure columns and format to display with $.

The only thing I couldn't do was edit to add "Person" heading, if you keep this as a pivot table which you can update. But you could just select your formatted pivot table and copy and paste to a new sheet and it is no longer a pivot table, just text.

[image]